# nested query for same table oracle

Tags: oracle

We have a table where we maintain the menu and submenus for the main menu,
for ex, I have the main menu called Warehouse->and submenus Admin and USer and user-profile and edit profile are nested menus for each submenu.
we have a column called function id and parent id to differentiate menu and its submenus suppose say functionid for a warehouse is 5 admin parent id will be 5 and function id of admin will be parent id for user-profile and edit profile, where functionid is unique for all and parentid will act as foreign key in the same table.

[image]

now I need to update the column say URL for only user profile which is under admin->warehouse. first, I tried with a select query like

```
  select * from  TIFX_CM_MENU_MAIN t1 where function='User Profile' and t1.PARENTID in
(select t2.FUNCTIONID from  TIFX_CM_MENU_MAIN t2 where t2.function='Admin' and t2.PARENTID in 
(select t3.FUNCTIONID from TIFX_CM_MENU_MAIN t3 where t3.function='WareHouse Operator')) ;
```

but looks some issue in the query, can anyone help me to get the expected result.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to understand and maintain this query (though it's might be a bit slower):

```
select t1.*
from TIFX_CM_MENU_MAIN t1
left join TIFX_CM_MENU_MAIN t2 on t1.PARENTID = t2.FUNCTIONID 
left join TIFX_CM_MENU_MAIN t3 on t2.PARENTID = t3.FUNCTIONID 
where t1.function = 'User Profile' and 
      t2.function = 'Admin' and 
      t3.function = 'WareHouse Operator';
```

Comment: Thank you Alex Larionov for your quick response. i tried to get count of above query it is giving count more than total count of table. m i doing wrong or i should try something to get count of only t1.*?

Comment: @Hema it means that `FUNCTIONID` is not a unique identifier of a row in your table, so you need to add another condition for both lines `on t1.PARENTID = t2.FUNCTIONID and t1.SOME_UNIQUE_ID= t2.SOME_UNIQUE_ID`, where `SOME_UNIQUE_ID` is a column that uniquely identifies a row (e.g. the primary key, or some another columns)